# Nested form - how to add existing nested object to parent form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, relationship

I've got my models setup for a many-to-many relationship:

```
class Workshop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workshop_students
  has_many :students, :through => :student_workshops

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_workshops
  has_many :workshops, :through => :student_workshops

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end

class StudentWorkshop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :workshop
end
```

As you can see above, a student can have many workshops and workshop can have many students.

I've looked at the following Rails casts: [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). And most of the online sources I stumble across only show how to do nested forms for creating new objects within the parent form.

I don't want to create a new object. I only want to add an existing object to the parent form. So for example. If I decide to create a new workshop, I'd like to assign existing students to the workshop.

One thing I don't understand is, how do I link students into the workshop form? Second, when the params are passed, what should be in the controller method for update/create?

If anyone can point me to the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: "Nested forms" aren't legal HTML.

Comment: I think he means nested objects within a single form.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for anyone coming across the same issue in the future. The solution I came up with was in def create. I am able to access a POST attribute called student_ids, which comes in the form of an array

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you did to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:student_ids, Student.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, {:selected => @workshop.student_ids, :multiple => true} )%>
```

You should not have to do anything in the create action.

Comment: I have learned from experience to avoid HABTM and use HMT (has_many :through => ).  This gives you a model with attributes you can add to later.  Even if 'later' only occurs 10% of the time, by that 'time' this stuff is embedded deeply and a major pain to change.  Better to have a flexible arrangment at the get go.  Some folks effectively consider HABTM to be deprecated at this point, i.e. it works but is not optimal.

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments. HABTM is not, and will not, be deprecated.